# how can I Optimize cuckoo hashing

Tags: python, optimization, hash, cryptography

I have a python code which implements cuckoo hashing.
I'm working on code for a hash table where collisions are corrected using cuckoo hashing. But it is taking a lot of time if there are more collisions.
I have used mmh3 family for hashing
so, is there a way to optimize this code and cuckoo hashing technique?
If yes kindly elaborate

```
from random import randint 
import math
import mmh3

#parameters
from parameters import output_bits, number_of_hashes
mask_of_power_of_2 = 2 ** output_bits - 1
log_no_hashes = int(math.log(number_of_hashes) / math.log(2)) + 1


#The hash family used for Cuckoo hashing relies on the Murmur hash family (mmh3)

def location(seed, item):
  '''
  :param seed: a seed of a Murmur hash function
  :param item: an integer
  :return: Murmur_hash(item_left) xor item_right, where item = item_left || item_right
  '''
  item_left = item >> output_bits
  item_right = item & mask_of_power_of_2
  hash_item_left = mmh3.hash(str(item_left), seed, signed=False) >> (32 - output_bits)
  return hash_item_left ^ item_right

def left_and_index(item, index): 
  '''
  :param item: an integer
  :param index: a log_no_hashes bits integer
  :return: an integer represented as item_left || index 
  '''
  return ((item >> (output_bits)) << (log_no_hashes)) + index     

def extract_index(item_left_and_index): 
  '''
  :param item_left_and_index: an integer represented as item_left || index
  :return: index extracted
  '''
  return item_left_and_index & (2 ** log_no_hashes - 1) 

def reconstruct_item(item_left_and_index, current_location, seed):
  '''
  :param item_left_and_index: an integer represented as item_left || index
  :param current_location: the corresponding location, i.e. Murmur_hash(item_left) xor item_right
  :param seed: the seed of the Murmur hash function
  :return: the integer item
  '''
  item_left = item_left_and_index >> log_no_hashes
  hashed_item_left = mmh3.hash(str(item_left), seed, signed=False) >> (32 - output_bits)
  item_right = hashed_item_left ^ current_location
  return (item_left << output_bits) + item_right

def rand_point(bound, i): 
  '''
  :param bound: an integer
  :param i: an integer less than bound
  :return: a uniform integer from [0, bound - 1], distinct from i
  '''
  value = randint(0, bound - 1)
  while (value == i):
      value = randint(0, bound - 1)
  return value    

class Cuckoo():

  def __init__(self, hash_seed):
      self.number_of_bins = 2 ** output_bits
      self.recursion_depth = int(8 * math.log(self.number_of_bins) / math.log(2))
      self.data_structure = [None for j in range(self.number_of_bins)]
      self.insert_index = randint(0, number_of_hashes - 1)
      self.depth = 0
      self.FAIL = 0

      self.hash_seed = hash_seed  

  def insert(self, item): #item is an integer
      current_location = location( self.hash_seed[self.insert_index], item)
      current_item = self.data_structure[ current_location]
      self.data_structure[ current_location ] = left_and_index(item, self.insert_index)

      if (current_item == None):
          self.insert_index = randint(0, number_of_hashes - 1)    
          self.depth = 0  
      else:
          unwanted_index = extract_index(current_item)
          self.insert_index = rand_point(number_of_hashes, unwanted_index)    
          if (self.depth < self.recursion_depth):
              self.depth +=1
              jumping_item = reconstruct_item(current_item, current_location, self.hash_seed[unwanted_index])
              self.insert(jumping_item)       
          else:
              self.FAIL = 1
```

Comment: I expect Python to be a big bottleneck here since the CPython interpreter is pretty slow and will clearly increase the latency of the hashing functions by a factor of 10-100x. Using the CPython interpreter for such critical data structure seems crazy. I advise you to use at least something like Cython or JITs to speed this up. That being said, `while (value == i)` may be the most critical part (when the structure is nearly full). This is hard to know in practice without profiling details or a benchmarking code. Can you provide that?

Comment: can you please tell me how exactly I can use Cython and JIT?

Comment: For Cython you can start to read the [tutorial](http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/tutorial/index.html) of the documentation. For JITs, the simpler is PyPy. You just need to install it and run your script with `pypy your_script.py`. Sometime it does not work because not all modules are supported. It is not always much faster too since Python is a dynamic language very hard to run efficiently. Cython solve this by transforming Python code to C based on native static typing. It is just a simpler way to write C modules.